# In Azure DevOps is it possible to run a YAML pipeline stage when a third party service returns certain payload (not status code)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to run a Veracode security scan on our big application. The problem is that the scan takes about 5 days and I do not want to keep the pipeline agent pinned down during all this time.

My current solution is this:

1. Have build 1 to upload the binaries and initiate the pre-scan.
2. Have build 2 run automatically when build 1 is over and poll the status of the upload. If the pre-scan is over - start the scan. If the scan is over - mark as success and clear the schedule. If the pre-scan or scan is still running - schedule the build 2 to run every 30 minutes from the current point in time by modifying the schedule in the build definition and mark the build as partially succeeded.

This scheme works, but I wonder if it can be simplified.

What if the build 2 was a Release tied to the build 1?

But is it possible to repeat the logic without scheduling a new Release every time and without pinning down the build agent for the entire duration of the scan (5 days) and by using YAML (i.e. unified pipeline instead of Build + Release) ?

After all, a single Release is able to deploy the same stage mutliple times - these are the different deployment attempts. The problem is that I do not know how to request an attempt in 30 minutes without just blocking the agent for the next 30 minutes, which is unacceptable.

So this brings up the question - can we use a YAML pipeline to start a build and then poll a third party service until it returns what we need (the payload must be parsed and examined, HTTP Status code is not enough) so that the next stage could run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the concept of "gates" or ["approvals and checks"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) depending on whether you're using YAML or classic pipelines.

You can add an "invoke REST API" check that periodically queries a REST endpoint and only proceeds when it satisfies the necessary conditions. This is a "serverless" operation -- it does not tie up an agent.

Comment: I know about these in the context of classic Release pipeline. But how does it work in YAML? I failed to figure it out. Also, the Invoke REST API check as far as I know does not allow me to process the result in order to decide, I think it is based on the status.

Comment: You attach the check to the Environment in which your job runs. You can provide an expression that evaluates the JSON response.